# Indexing in python (enumeration method)

Tags: python, indexing

Light question in the evening :D

```
string  = 'S40S'
for char in string:
    print(string.index(char))

#Returns
0
1
2
0
```

If I want to receive the index of a certain string. Why would the index of the last Char be 0 instead of 3???

Comment: Don't **ever** do this. This is 1) as you've found out, incorrect and 2) highly inefficient (makes your algorithm at least quadratic time)

Comment: "Why would the index of the last Char be 0 instead of 3???" Because, that is how the index method works. It returns the first index of the substring you pass to `string.index`. Why did you *expect* `string.index("S")` to return two different values?

Comment: Your title, description and question are all 3 different things, which are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

Because `index` takes the first value.
So your loop is going over the characters, at the end it encounters an S.

It runs `'S40S'.index('S')` and the result is 0 - the first encounter of S.

Instead, you can use:

```
string  = 'S40S'
for i, char in enumerate(string):
    print(string[i])
```

Or more simply if you don't need `char`:

```
string  = 'S40S'
for i in range(len(string)):
    print(string[i])
```